# "How to fix 'selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined' error in selenium jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, mousehover

I am running my selenium code written in Java on Jenkins server. I used Actions class for mouse hovering. Used Chrome browser. It's working perfectly fine when I run it on my local machine. But not working when I run the same on jenkins. I am getting an error message at the moveToElement function. Error is:

> org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Cannot read
>   property 'left' of undefined

Following options tried.

1:Using actions class

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(WebElement).build.perform();
```

2:Using javaScript

```
String strJavaScript = "var element = arguments[0]; var mouseEventObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); mouseEventObj.initEvent( 'mouseover', true, true ); element.dispatchEvent(mouseEventObj);";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) BrowserFunctionality.getBrowser()).executeScript(strJavaScript, linkNameElement);
```

Note: Used scrolltoview as well in javascript

3: Using Robot class

```
Point coordinates =webElement.getLocation();
         Robot robot = new Robot();
         robot.mouseMove(0,0);
        robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY()+120);
```

Tried these options with and without below chrome Option:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.HAS_NATIVE_EVENTS,false);
```

Hover it is not working in Jenkins. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try the following: 1)Open browser window on full screen  
 2) Run your job on JNLP Jenkins agent

Comment: @DebanjanB - I dont think this is a duplicate issue. Issue is occurring when the code is run via Jenkins on Jenkins server. It works on local machine. Please read the issue fully before marking it as duplicate

Comment: @kumargtg _property 'left' of undefined_ , of coarse you need to **wait**

Comment: I got similar error in such string just by launching test in IDE: `act.moveToElement(getListElements(listItemName)).click(getListElements(listItemName)).build().perform();`
In my case I have a deal with drop down multi select list when open it and try to click Item with known name.
It is not a duplicate question because of errors and languages are different.

Comment: There is an issue logged against Chrome driver 76. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7498